# GWT Download Excel .xlsx gives me a corrupted file

Tags: java, excel, gwt, download

I'm working on a GWT application which gives every team in the company an overview about what they have to do.
The program is working, but now we want that the Excel table which you can download will be a .xlsx and not a .xls.
This whole project is new for me and I consider myself as a beginner in GWT.

In the code, when the filename is given for the Excel table, there is a `+".xls"` at the end. When I change it to `+".xlsx"` and test the application, the download still works. However, when I try to open the file in Excel, it shows me an error message and tells me the file is corrupted. (.xls works)

Can you explain to me how a download works in GWT with a serverSite generated Excel?
Maybe you have some ideas what causes the file to be corrupted
(sadly the programmer of this application is on holiday, so I cannot ask him)

```
public class Download extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5580666921970339383L;
    
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String filename = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute(CrossReportConstants.ATTR_FILENAME);
        byte[] data = (byte[])request.getSession().getAttribute(CrossReportConstants.ATTR_REPORT);
        request.getSession().setAttribute(CrossReportConstants.ATTR_FILENAME, null);
        request.getSession().setAttribute(CrossReportConstants.ATTR_REPORT, null);
        
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        response.setContentLength(data.length);

        try {
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

            byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
            // copy binary contect to output stream
            while (in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1) {
                out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code which you are trying to change? Sounds like you are just changing the name of the file in the http response, but not the content type.

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt The problem is im not really allowed to post code here.... and the whole Project is relatively big it got over 80 classes and at the moment im trying to figure out where i have to change something....sadly i cannot ask my coworker because he is on holidays....if I find the code part i will share it

Comment: If it is a HttpServlet look for something like response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt i added the code where i found "response.setContentType..." - can u explain to me how the download works with a servelet or can u recommend a good tutorial?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading excel file from spring java causing file to corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649165/downloading-excel-file-from-spring-java-causing-file-to-corrupt)

Answer (score 0):

Now as you provided code you question can be easily answered:

The shown code defines a `HttpServlet`. Somewhere in your project there is a file called `web.xml`. In this file the class you showed is mapped to an url pattern, therefore you server knows that a specific url should be handled by this servlet.

The servlet you showed first extracts the file name and the file content out of the session. Additional the http response is prepared and the file content is written out. Now you just have to replace the content type of the response with the one for xlsx.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

The browser which handles the http response now recognizes the download as a .xlsx file. The file extension does not really matter in this step, as you noticed.

When the original programmer of the servlet comes back from his hollidays, you should/could recommend him to use `response.sendError()`  (with an appropriate http status code) instead of  `e.printStackTrace()`. Then the user of the servlet can better understand if something do not work and who is to blame.

Comment: i changed
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
to
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

and changed the generatet filename to .xmsx but when i test it it downloads a .xslx sheet but i cannot open it Excel still tells me the file is corrupted