# Downloading excel file from spring java causing file to corrupt

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am trying to call this method from my filter and i am successfully able to download the excel but after the download when i open the excel it shows that it is corrupted but when i see the file on server files opens fine without any error.

***Excel error : excel cannot open the file "filename" because the file format or file extension is not valid.***

```
public static void downloadFileFromServer(HttpServletResponse response, String sourceFile,
            Boolean isFilenameHavingTimestamp,Boolean deleteTempFile) throws IOException, Exception {
        logger.debug("Inside ServiceUtils.downloadFileFromServer()");
        // splitting serverPath and fileName
        String serverHomeDirectory[] = sourceFile.split("\\\\|/");
        String fileName = serverHomeDirectory[serverHomeDirectory.length - 1];
        fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileName, "UTF-8");
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isFilenameHavingTimestamp)) {
            fileName = removeTimestampFromFilename(fileName);
        }

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        try (ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);) {
            int octet = 0;
            while ((octet = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(octet);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in ServiceUtils.downloadFileFromServer(): ", e);
            throw new Exception(ExceptionMessage.ERROR_DOWNLOAD_EXCEL_FILE);
        } finally {
            
            // check if file needs to be deleted after download
            /*if(deleteTempFile)
                deleteTempFile(sourceFile);*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the response already had a string and code was writing the file appending the existing response in the buffer.

Solved the problem by adding below code before setContentType()

```
response.reset();
```